# DataTrigger on WPF Animation

Tags: wpf, animation, backgroundworker, datatrigger

My application has a few background worker, each doing different work. When I click the 'Start' button, all backgroundworker will start simultaneously.

in my xaml, I had defined my animation of a rotate image:

```
<window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="imageRotate">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="transRotate"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                From="0" To="360"
                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                AutoReverse="False"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
     </Storyboard>
</window.Resources>
```

I want the animation to begin when all the backgroundworker started, and stop ONLY after ALL background worker stopped.

I have a property call AreWorkersBusy:

```
private bool _areWorkerBusy;
public bool AreWorkerBusy
{
    get
    {
        return _areWorkerBusy;
    }
    set
    {
        bool isBusy = false;
        foreach(BackgroundWorker worker in BackgroundWorkerList)
        {
            if(worker.IsBusy)
                 isBusy = true;
        }
        _areWorkerBusy = isBusy;
    }
}
```

but it's not dependencyProperty, so I can't bind to my animation's DataTrigger.

Any workaround???

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible ways,

You can implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify 'AreWorkerBusy' changes, create a dependency property  in the control and bind 'AreWorkerBusy' with it.

Create two routed events one to start animation and another to stop animation.

In the property changed handler for your DP, raise the specific routed event.

In your control write event triggers, and based on the event start of stop the animation.

I had written a similar experience, http://keepitsimpleengineer.blogspot.com/2010/09/wpf-circular-progress-control-part-2.html